# В чем разница между присоединительными союзами "И" и "А"?

Tags: союзы

Разъясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между присоединительными союзами "И" и "А"?
Примеры с союзом "И":

1. Он имел власть в городе, **и** не малую.
2. Сегодня обязательно сделай уборку в квартире, **и** сходи в магазин.

Примеры с союзом "А":

1. Завтра мы сначала пойдем на охоту, **а** потом на рыбалку.
2. На поляне стояла избушка, **а** в избушке жил старик.

В каких случаях применяется союза "А", а в каких "И"?

Answer (score 1):

**Примеры с союзом "И"**

1. *Он имел власть в городе, **и не малую.***

Союз И **присоединительный**, можно заменить присоединительным союзом «причем».

2. *Сегодня обязательно сделай уборку в квартире, **и еще** сходи в магазин.***

Здесь **однородные** сказуемые, но союз тоже **присоединительный** (дополнительная информация). Однако такой союз  нужно **отличать** от соединительного, поэтому лучше добавить наречие "еще" в качестве структурного элемента.

**Примеры с союзом "А"**

1. *Завтра мы **сначала** пойдем на охоту, **а потом** на рыбалку.*

Союз А **сопоставительный** (сочинительный): сначала на охоту, а потом на рыбалку.

2. *На поляне стояла избушка, **а в избушке жил старик.***

Это самый интересный пример.

Предложения в составе ССП связаны **однородными** отношениями.
С одной стороны, это последовательность изложения событий в сказочном зачине, и **какой-то союз** нужен. Попробуем **выбрать** между сочинительными союзами А и И.

Союз И **распространительный**, второе предложение продолжает тему первого, отношения между предложения **неоднородные**.

Союз А **сопоставительный**, отношения **однородные.** Автор как бы предлагает нам **независимые картинки:** вот одна, а вот другая, не связывая их союзом ***И***. И тогда возникает особое,  «сказочное» настроение.

**[Особый сказочный зачин](https://alfacasting.ru/faq/osobyi-skazocnyi-zacin-tainy-i-sekrety)**

*В мире литературы существует множество различных **приемов и стилей,** которые помогают авторам создавать увлекательные и запоминающиеся произведения. Один из таких приемов, который широко применяется в литературе, это особый **сказочный зачин.** Этот прием помогает автору создать **загадочное и интересное начало истории,** что привлекает внимание читателя и заставляет его продолжать чтение произведения.*

**[О союзе А](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf). стр 225**

Comment: Не совсем понял почему во втором примере союз А сопоставительный? Речь же не идет о сравнении двух отличающихся чем-то картинок.

Comment: Вот еще одно интересное предложение "Вы вчера ушли раньше времени, а зря". В данном случае союз А  присоединительный или сопоставительный?

Comment: Можно, конечно, союз И использовать, но я обратила внимание, что в сказках часто используется союз А. Вот и стала думать, чем он лучше. И представила, как мы ведем рассказ в картинках.  Вот одна картинка-сообщение, а вот другая.  Если взять союз И, то  будет просто последовательность сообщений. Но это мое представление  о сказочной теме, можно предложить другую версию.  Задайте отдельный вопрос, интересно ведь!

Comment: Вы вчера ушли раньше времени, а зря (вы так сделали). А какой еще союз взять: И, НО? Они не подходят, лучше сопоставить события. И теперь о ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОМ значении. Присоединение – это добавочное сообщение (определяется по тексту). В качестве присоединительных союзов можно использовать разные слова и союзы, можно посмотреть у Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120В частности он приводит примеры с присоединительным (сочинительным) союзом И. Союзы А и НО редко встретишь в качестве присоединительных, но бывает и такое.

Comment: Еще любопытная тема: почему мы союз А часто используем в начале предложения в различных текстах. Что он-то там делает?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что сопоставляется в предложении "Вы вчера ушли раньше времени, а зря"? Первое событие "Вы ушли раньше времени", а второе событие в чем?

Comment: Когда мы строим нашу речь, то каждое следующее сообщение можем представить как соединение, присоединение, сопоставление, противопоставление.  Точно так же и в этом случае, где просматривается такой смысл: вы вот ушли, а сделали  это зря.  Здесь два сообщения: сопоставляется событие и оценка этого события.

Comment: Мне кажется, что союз И в присоединительном значении применяется тогда, когда к первому высказыванию есть еще что добавить (какую-то новую информацию), т.е тогда когда первая часть содержит не полную информацию.

Comment: Что касается присоединительного союза А, мне кажется, что он присоединяет дополнения, которые развивают начатую мысль. И в этом, по моему мнению, его отличие от присоединительного союза И.

Comment: В частных случаях да, но обобщать бы я не стала. Надо знать специфику каждого союза и использовать его в тексте с нужным смыслом. (При этом присоединительные конструкции  – это вообще отдельная тема.)  По тексту видно, когда мы дополняем информацию (присоединительное значение) или когда собираемся продолжить свою мысль.