# Присоединительный союз «а»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, присоединительный-союз, присоединение

Возник вопрос по поводу союза А, имеющего присоединительное значение. Примеров не будет — скорее наоборот, мне нужны будут примеры. Возник вопрос: а существует ли союз А как присоединительный? Если да, можете привести примеры с таким союзом? Только нужно, чтоб присоединительный оборот с этим союзом был с двух сторон обособлен, а не стоял в конце. Союз А ТАКЖЕ и другие союзы, в составе которых есть ещë что-то, кроме *а*, не считаются. Просто интересно узнать немного побольше о русском языке.

Comment: Похожий вопрос задавался, но мы с автором немного не сошлись во взглядах Все собираюсь дать второй ответ, да никак не соберусь) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475368/В-чем-разница-между-присоединительными-союзами-И-и-А   А вы сами можете придумать хотя бы один пример с присоединительным союзом?

Comment: @Sharon Нет, это мне примеры нужны, да и такие, чтобы оборот не стоял в конце предложения.

Comment: Вы как царевна из сказки: "Построй мне  дворец, да такой, чтобы равных ему не было".  Одиночный присоединительный союз А и в конце предложения не так просто найти))

Comment: Если вот только Морковкин поможет...  Но хотелось бы еще в конце предложения, но это уже мое желание)

Comment: Очень много присоединительных союзов А в середине предложения   у Розенталя, пункт 4 
 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведу выдержку из ***«Большого универсального словаря русского языка» под ред. Морковкина***:

> **А**… 5.2. *присоед.* Употр. для введения в сообщение какого-л. факультативного, ассоциативного и т. п. примечания, замечания, к-рое
> возникает по поводу содержания этого сообщения, по ходу высказывания и
> т. п. # ***Син.*** же *употр. реже*.
>
> *Я думаю, что Мухин, **а он старожил здешних мест**, лучше расскажет вам об истории посёлка. К началу концерта — **а он начинается в семь
> вечера** — мы обязательно успеем. Сейчас в этом здании, **а это бывший
> клуб**, выставочный зал. Весной, **а весна — мое любимое время года**,
> здесь просто чудесно.*